# How to get a Keras layer function's argument value from a dict based on the argument name?

Tags: python, keras

I'm creating a Keras based deep learning model. Since my model can have various architectures and hyperparameter values, I'd like to have the flexibility in my `create_model` function to take a list of layers `layers_list` together with hyperparameter values `params`, so that the `create_model` function can compile the model accordingly for later use.

Here's my `create_model` function:

```
def create_model(layers_list, 
                 params,
                 optimizer='adam',
                 loss='binary_crossentropy',
                 metrics=['categorical_accuracy']):
    model = Sequential(layers_list)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=metrics)

    return model
```

Ideally, I should be able to provide a `params` dict like this:

```
{'max_words': 30000,
 'embedding_dim': 60,
 'maxlen': 70,
 'dropout_rate': 0.3,
 'filters': 300,
 'kernel_size': 11}
```

And a `layers_list` like this, where all the arguments are automatically found from the `params` dict and populated in the `layers_list`.

```
layers_list = [
    Embedding(input_dim,
              output_dim,
              input_length,
    Conv1D(filters,
           kernel_size,
           activation='relu'),
    GlobalMaxPooling1D(),
    Dense(276),
    Activation('sigmoid')
]
```

Of course, I can assign each parameter like this:

```
input_dim = params['max_words']
```

but I'm wondering whether there's a less manual and more elegant way of doing this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question, you want to dynamically fill the parameters in your list of layers. What I would do for that is to create a dummy function that returns you the list of layers with the parameters filled in from the dictionary, automatically. For that, you have to define the function as follows and then unroll the dictionary using the `**` trick:

First we define the function with the layer architecture

```
def get_layer_list(input_dim, output_dim, input_length, filters, kernel_size):
    layer_list = [
                  Embedding(input_dim,
                            output_dim),
                  Conv1D(filters,
                         kernel_size,
                         activation='relu'),
                  GlobalMaxPooling1D(),
                  Dense(276),
                  Activation('sigmoid')]
    return layer_list
```

And then we define the parameters dict to fill them into the previous list.

```
params = {"input_dim": (4096,),
          "output_dim": (1,),
          "input_length": 16,
          "filters": 128,
          "kernel_size": (3, 3)}
```

And finally we can call the function for automatically fill in the parameter values as follows.

```
get_layer_list(**params)
```

And then your final function would be something like the following, where the `layers_list_generator` parameter in the function would be your `get_layer_list` function in this case:

```
def create_model(layers_list_generator, 
                 params,
                 optimizer='adam',
                 loss='binary_crossentropy',
                 metrics=['categorical_accuracy']):
    layers_list = layers_list_generator(**params)
    model = Sequential(layers_list)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=metrics)

    return model
```

Hope it helps :D

Comment: I.e. you would call it as:
`create_model(get_layer_list, params, optimizer='Adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])`

Comment: Thanks! However, this doesn't seem to work...If you use `params = {"input_dim": 30000, "output_dim": 60, "input_length": 70, "filters": 300 "kernel_size": 11}`, you'll get `TypeError: Embedding can accept only 2 positional arguments ('input_dim', 'output_dim'), but you passed the following positional arguments: [30000, 60, 70]`.

Comment: Of course, it is an example of how can you input your arguments automatically from a dict object. Now you have to tweak it for your application. In this case, the mistake is in your example

Comment: Just review Keras documentation.